# Struts: How to get the type of a tile attribute

Tags: xml, jsp, struts, tiles

Consider this tile definition-

```
<definition name=".feedback.form.header" extends=".header.setup">
  <put name="description" value="/common/subheader/feedback_description.jsp"
   type="page"/>
</definition>

<definition name=".experience.form.header" extends=".header.setup">
  <put name="description" value="Welcome"
   type="string"/>
</definition>
```

Notice the difference in the `type` attribute for `description` in the above two definitions. Is there a way to know what type of description it is in a jsp page where this tile is used?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to include a JSP in first case and a string in the second.
It's not a problem. Using tiles:insertAttribute will insert correctly the attribute following the correct strategy depending on the type itself.